# ValueError: feature_names must contain 155 elements, got 19

Tags: random-forest, valueerror

I built a Random Forest classification model and when I try to view the decision trees in it by running this code:

```
from sklearn.tree import export_text

print(export_text(tr_classifier.estimators_[0], 
              spacing=3, decimals=3,
              feature_names=X.columns))
```

I get this error: ValueError: feature_names must contain 155 elements, got 19

This are the columns in my prediction data:

```
X.columns

Index(['Age', 'Ethnicity', 'Gender', 'Diagnosis', 'IPSS-R', 'Blasts %',
   'Plate_count', 'Platelet_volume', 'RBC', 'WBC', 'Hgb', 'HCT',
   'Blood type', 'Neutrophils (absolute/%)', 'Lymphocytes (absolute/%)',
   'Monocytes (absolute/%)', 'Eosinophils (absolute/%)',
   'Basophils (absolute/%)', 'Treatment'],
  dtype='object')
```

Comment: Please check my answer. I'd be happy to get some feedback

Comment: Yes, I used plot_tree instead but this works too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataFrame` has some columns which could potentially be categorical, e.g. `'Ethnicity'` or `'Gender'`. Have you performed one-hot encoding, e.g. `OneHotEncoder` or `pd.get_dummies` ? In this case, new columns are created. Is it possible you assigned the original `X` instead of the encoded `X_train`?

This might explain the mismatch of columns. In this case, the solution is to use `feature_names=X_train.columns`:

```
from sklearn.tree import export_text

print(export_text(tr_classifier.estimators_[0], 
              spacing=3, decimals=3,
              feature_names=X_train.columns))
```